# System only recognizes 24GB of RAM, won't boot depending on BIOS settings

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

Until now, my computer ran with 16 GB (2x8) of RAM just fine with the default optimized BIOS settings. Now I wanted to upgrade with another pair of 2x8GB, but as soon as I insert them, the computer won't boot at all and keeps looping on a 'bd' error code with no POST.

When I run a memtest (memOK!), it passes the 'bd' code and gives a POST saying everying is okay. When I apply the settings, it keeps hanging on 'b6' code and shuts down shortly after. When I don't apply the settings and just reboot, the system boots just fine and appears stable, however it only recognizes 24GB of RAM.

Specs:
**MoBo**: ASUS X99-A II (SOCKET 2011)
**CPU**: Intel Core i7 6800K @ 3.40GHz Broadwell-E/EP
**RAM**: Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4-3000MHz (8GB), 4pcs.

What I did:

1. I tested every RAM and RAM slot individually, to ensure everything works hardware related.
2. I upgraded to the latest available BIOS version through EZ Update (build 1701)
3. Ran memOK! memtest, everything fine (code b6 crash)
4. Reset BIOS to optimized default (code bd loop)
5. Set BIOS to AI Tuner optimized settings (code b6 crash)
6. Enabled XMP (which targets the RAM at 3000MHz), (code b6 crash)
7. Disabled XMP, slowly raised VCCSA (system agent voltage) by 0.1v, stopped trying at 1.20V

What else could I try?